# How to config specific fragment's orientation when orientation change?

Tags: android, orientation, android-fragments

I have multiple fragments inside `MainActivity` I want to config on orientation change only in `DetailFragment`

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment{
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            WindowManager wm = getActivity().getWindowManager();

            Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            if(d.getWidth() > d.getHeight()){
                mDetailView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false);
            }else{
                mDetailView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_port, container, false);
            }
            gridView = (GridView)mDetailView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        return mDetailView;
        }
}
```

so, I have to override `onConfigurationChanged` in `SubTopicFragment` Below is some part of `SubTopicFragment extend ListFragment`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    updateDetial(topic_index, args.getString("group_id"), args.getString("group_name"));
}

public void updateDetial(int subTopicPosition,String groupID, String groupName){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    DetailFragment detailView = (DetailFragment)getFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFrame);
    DetailFragment detailFrag = new DetailFragment(topic_index, subTopicPosition, groupID, groupName);

    if(detailView==null){

        ft.add(R.id.detailFrame, detailFrag);
        ft.commit();
    }else{
        ft.replace(R.id.detailFrame, detailFrag);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

It work well. But the problem occurs when **I move to another activity then,change orientation  and press back Button, it cause force close** How can I fix this?

```
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1192)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1203)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:557)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:541)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.april.android.SubTopicFragment.updateDetial(SubTopicFragment.java:120)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.april.android.SubTopicFragment.onConfigurationChanged(SubTopicFragment.java:259)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchConfigurationChanged(FragmentManager.java:1706)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.Activity.onConfigurationChanged(Activity.java:1402)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3298)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleActivityConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3427)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1113)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-13 10:15:54.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The clue is in "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" but we'd need more lines of your stack trace to see what's really happening.

Comment: It has something to do with the order in which you do things, like a fragment gets closed during rotation and after that, another part of your code calls a method in the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everything about your code is wrong.

```
        Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        if(d.getWidth() > d.getHeight()){
            mDetailView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false);
        }else{
            mDetailView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_port, container, false);
        }
        gridView = (GridView)mDetailView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
```

Don't do this - The platform has it's own way of loading layouts by using the naming convention. Your code should look like this:

```
    mDetailView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView)mDetailView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
```

If you want it to look different in different orientations place two detail.xml files in both `layout-port` and `layout-land` and the OS will load the correct one (and deal with deduping all of your resource ids which is likely your problem). Also:

```
DetailFragment detailView = (DetailFragment)getFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFrame);
DetailFragment detailFrag = new DetailFragment(topic_index, subTopicPosition, groupID, groupName);

if(detailView==null){

    ft.add(R.id.detailFrame, detailFrag);
    ft.commit();
}else{
    ft.replace(R.id.detailFrame, detailFrag);
    ft.commit();
}
```

You gain access to the Fragment present already. You then create a whole new Fragment. You then check to see if your first Fragment is null before adding the new one anyway? .add() and .replace() are different because add() specifically doesn't remove the previous fragment - replace() will not throw an error however if there isn't a previous fragment to remove so you can use this every time.

```
    ft.replace(R.id.detailFrame, new DetailFragment(topic_index, subTopicPosition, groupID, groupName);
    ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have two different layout id to load in onCreateView

Use one layout Id for both your layout

What you can do is

R.layout.detail in layout folder

R.layout.detail_port rename it to R.layout.detail and place it in layout-port folder of res

Then inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false); will automatically give the specific layout based on orientation

Read this documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: I change my code according to your advice. It's a good thing I forgot to do. Anyway, I try rotate device, the grid detail still use init value that it first start with, I need to select another topic so that it will replace new grid that correspond to is's orientation. Do you have any idea, how to make detail's view update its view immediately after orientation change?